# Как написать это на php?

Tags: php

Приквел:
в php я <=0;

Суть:

Есть форма на сайте, ниже кусок кода, который берет данные с формы и вставляет их в файл .tpl в соответствующие места.

Пример tpl:

```
<table border="0" style="background:#f3f5f6;color:#333;padding:50px">
  <tr>
    <td>%%emai.title%%</td>
    <td>%%email.value%%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

С ним работает php:

```
function tpl($vars) {
    $tpl = 'tpl/'.$vars['name'].'.tpl';
    if(file_exists($tpl)) {
     $template = file_get_contents($tpl);
        foreach($vars['getdata'] as $name => $data) {
            $template = str_replace(array("%%".$name.".title%%", "%%".$name.".value%%"), array($data['title'], $data['value']), $template);
        }    

//здесь я пробовал использовать свои знания php:
if($data['value']===''){
        $this echo('не заполнено');
        }
//конец знаний

 return $template;
    }
     else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

То есть я хотел сделать следующее:

Если поле на сайте не заполнено, то на почту приходит так **%%emai.title%% %%emai.value%%** каждое незаполненное поле, а заполненное приходит нормально как и должно быть.

Вот как мне написать скрипт чтобы если не заполнено поле, то приходит на почту заместо **%%emai.title%%** нормальное название поля и его значение "не заполнено"?

Answer (score 2):

Надо определить пустые значения, как "не заполнено"

Например можно сделать так:

```
    foreach($vars['getdata'] as $name => $data) {
        $title = empty($data['title']) ? 'не заполнено' : $data['title'];
        $value = empty($data['value']) ? 'не заполнено' : $data['value'];
        $template = str_replace(array("%%".$name.".title%%", "%%".$name.".value%%"), array($title, $value), $template);
    }
```